# Pandas calculate median after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to answer below question for a Dataframe as snapshot. I try following Code it returns error of as shown below. If i removed a column in the groupby. The code will not return error. Please advise.

```
df.loc[df.age_group == pd.Interval(left=30, right=40)].groupby(df[['Gender','Education']]).DMDHHSIZ.median()
```

```
ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional
```

*Question:Restrict the sample to people between 30 and 40 years of age. Then calculate the median household size for women and men within each level of educational attainment.*

[image]

Comment: You groupby should be a list, not a dataframe

Comment: but age_group is a string which denotates an interval, and you are compareing it with the result of median() which is a float. And what is DMDHHSIZ?

Comment: Thanks, removing the dataframe works. DMDHHSIZ is the Householdsize series.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a list of columns to groupby:

`.groupby(['Gender','Education'])`

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. Still not familiar with Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

From the statement and the image:

> Question:Restrict the sample to people between 30 and 40 years of age.
> Then calculate the median household size for women and men within each
> level  of educational attainment.

Then you can first filter the `age_group`, following the pattern in the image would be `(30,40]`, then you calculate the `median()` after `grouping` by `Gender` and `Education`.

```
df.loc[df.age_group == '(30,40]'].groupby(['Gender','Education']).DMDHHSIZ.median()
```